# How to get a list of lists from a string containing a NumPy value?

Tags: python, string, numpy

I have a Python script that parses inputs from the command line. One of these arguments is a string containing a list of lists (e.g. `python myscript.py -b '[[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]]'`).
There are several ways in which I can directly convert this string into a list of lists, like `json.loads()` or `ast.literal_eval()`.

It might be useful for me to be able to include NumPy values in this string, like `'[[0, 2*np.pi],[-np.pi/2, np.pi/2]]'` and still be able to convert this string into a list of lists. However, none of the two methods mentioned above seems to work and I couldn't find anything suitable online.
Does anyone know a method that is able to handle this?
I'd rather not to write a method myself if something suitable already exists.

Comment: You can use `eval()`. Also if you import `pi` directly (e.g. `from math import pi` or `from numpy import pi`), you could parse this `'[[0, 2*pi],[-pi/2, pi/2]]'`.

Comment: Technically, `eval` *can* be used, but introduces security vulnerability.  TBH, I’d recommend writing your own method, even if it just wraps `eval` with the view of sanity checking the statement to be evaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `eval()`:

```
import numpy as np
string = '[[0, 2*np.pi],[-np.pi/2, np.pi/2]]'
eval(string)

OUTPUT:
[[0, 6.283185307179586], [-1.5707963267948966, 1.5707963267948966]]
```

NOTE: there are some downsides when using `eval`, see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice/1832957#1832957).

Comment: Please attach a caveat to using `eval`, as the user *must* understand *exactly* what is being evaluated. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/6340496). Generally, `ast.literal_eval` should be used, but will not work in this case.